# Cannot Read Property of Dynamically Created Checkbox after DOM is Loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an application that allows users to select one or more courses. The user may choose to save the selected courses and come back later to finish the process. When/if the user returns, I recreate the list of checkboxes. Then, I try to find all the input checkboxes within that div. I log it to the console, and it returns an empty collection. How do I obtain the checkboxes properties?

**The empty div that is populated with the checkboxes.**

```
 <div class="courseList applyBackgroundColor" id="UserCheckList">

 </div>
```

**Where I am doing the post and creating the dynamic textboxes using the result.**

```
var createCourse = function(studentID)
{ 
  var StudentCourseList = '<table><tbody>';
   do post here

 $.each(result, function (index, item) {
     StudentCourseList  += '<td valign="top" style="width:1%" id=td.ck.' +  
     item.ID + '><div class=""><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"  
     id="'+ item.ID + '" value="' + item.ID + '" /></div></td>
    <td valign="top" style="width:30%;padding:.25em;" id="' + item.ID +
     '"><span id="span.' + item.ID + '" title="' + item.Description + '">' 
     + item.Description             +'</span></td>';

}

   $('#UserCheckList').html(StudentCourseList );
}
```

**Checking if there is a student id when the page loads.**

```
$(function(){
  var studentID = $('#studentID').val(); 
  if(studentID !==''){
    createCourse(studentID);
    var listCheckUsers = $('.courseList').find('input[type=checkbox]');
    console.log(listCheckUsers);
```

**if I put a breakpoint next to listCheckUsers and debug it, the result that is displayed in the console is shown below:**

```
      Object[input#MAC201.checkbox attribute value = "MATH 201",   
      input#ENC101.checkbox attribute value = "ENGLISH 101",....]
  }
```

**without the breakpoint, I see an empty object**

```
  Object[]
});
```

**Updated:** Adding the exact JQuery message.

```
//This is shown when I do not use a breakpoint.

1.  jQuery.fn.init[0]
  1.    context: document
  2.    length: 0
  3.    prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1]
    1.  0: div#UserCheckList.Display
    2.  context: document
    3.  length: 1
    4.  selector: "#UserCheckList"
    5.  __proto__: jQuery[0]
  4.    selector: "#UserCheckList input[type=checkbox]"
  5.    __proto__: jQuery[0]
```

Comment: What element in your HTML has a `class='courseList'`?

Comment: This line should have been $('#UserCheckList').html(StudentCourseList );. The html5 looks like this.               <div class="courseList applyBackgroundColor" id="UserCheckList">

              </div>

Comment: it should work as long as you do not have any other script errors http://jsbin.com/merujulode/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the className `courseList` in the table element.

*update*
I simulated an Ajax request by using setTimeout.  You can remove the setTimeout code and put an Ajax request in place.  When the data is returned run your callback function with the data.

```js
function getResults(studentID, callback) {

  // Async call.
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Replace generator with Ajax call
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var item = {
        ID: i,
        "Description": "Result #" + i
      };
      result.push(item);
    }
    // Run this when data returns.
    callback(result);
  }, 3000);

  // Show loading while we wait.
  $('.UserCheckList').html('loading...');
}

function showResults(result) {
  var StudentCourseList = '<table class="courseList"><tbody>';

  $.each(result, function(index, item) {
    StudentCourseList += '<tr><td valign="top" style="width:1%" id=td.ck.' +
      item.ID + '><div class=""><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"\
     id="' + item.ID + '" value="' + item.ID + '" /></div></td>\
    <td valign="top" style="width:30%;padding:.25em;" id="' + item.ID +
      '"><span id="span.' + item.ID + '" title="' + item.Description + '">' + item.Description + '</span></td></tr>';

  });

  $('.UserCheckList').html(StudentCourseList);
}


$(function() {
      var studentID = $('#studentID').val();
      if (studentID !== '') {
        getResults(studentID, function(results) {
          // callback when results are complete.
          showResults(results);

          var listCheckUsers = $('.courseList').find('input[type=checkbox]');
          console.log(listCheckUsers);
        });
      }
}); //end
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="UserCheckList"></div>
```

Comment: I updated the code. UserCheckList is an id and not a class, so I replace it with the '#UserCheckList' instead of '.UserCheckList'. Also, If I used the browser debugger to step through it, the object is not empty and all properties are included in the console. However,  the moment I removed the breakpoint and ran it, it displayed an empty object.

Comment: @JeanB are you making an Ajax request?  If you are then the breakpoint may be giving it time to complete whereas no breakpoint tries to show results before they're returned.  You would need a callback function on the data request that works on the result

Comment: I am fairly new to JavaScript. I am reading up on callback function and trying to use that.